# pythonでのデコレーターに関して

Tags: python

python初心者です。
デコレーターがどういうものなのか、どういった時に必要となるのかが理解できません。
例とともに教えていただけたら幸いです。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

例えば標準ライブラリに functools.lru_cache というデコレータがあります。

このデコレータは、たとえば自分で作成した関数が実行にある程度長い時間がかかる(1秒程度)けれども、関数の引数に対して返値がずっと変わらない、あるいは一定期間変わらない場合に使用します。

```
def get_first_image(url):
    """与えられたURLのページを開いて、HTML内からリンクされている一番大きな画像データを返す"""
    # ここに実装
    return image_data
```

こんな関数を実装した場合実行に2,3秒くらいかかるかもしれません。もしこの関数に同じURLを何度も指定する可能性があるなら、URLに対する結果をキャッシュしておけば2回目以降の実行は速く返せるはずです。

そこで、以下のように書きます。

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache()
def get_first_image(url):
    """与えられたURLのページを開いて、HTML内からリンクされている一番大きな画像データを返す"""
    # ここに実装
    return image_data
```

これでキャッシュされるようになりました。

decoratorを使えば関数の呼び出しに対して処理を付加できます。今回の例では、get_first_imageという関数にキャッシュ機能を付加しました。デコレータは、対象関数の呼び出しに対する結果を変えないのが原則です。デコレータを使えば関数の返値を書き換えたりもできてしまいますが、利用者はそのようは副作用があると混乱するので、やらないほうがよいでしょう。